# How to get a Google talk api key?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, google-plus, flurry, google-talk

I am developing a Google talk application for WP7. How can i get a Google talk api key, flurry api key, and plus api keys? I couldn't find anywhere to get these keys.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a api key! You only need to adhere to [XMPP specs](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/rfcs/). These two links should come in handy if you want to develop a Gtalk client for wp7:

https://developers.google.com/talk/talk_developers_home

http://www.programmableweb.com/api/google-talk

I use the second one a lot as it provides useful info about various API's and hence can act as a starting know-how guide!

Comment: If the gchat API offers that then it should be possible. This is not dependent on WP7 but dependent on the google API. You would need to look up their API